# If function in Makefile seems to disregard conditional and executes unexpectedly

Tags: gnu-make

The following is a simple recipe that is not behaving as I want it to:

`$(eval PkgName := $(shell pacman -Qq zsh | awk '{print $$1}'))`

`$(if ifeq ($(strip ${PkgName}),), pacman -Sy --noconfirm zsh)`

All I want it to do is, to install a package iff it has not been installed previously.  The installation executes successfully if the package doesn't exist in the system.  However, it also executes if it is already installed.

I have tried the GNU make conditional ifeq with the same outcome.

How can I avoid it to execute if the package already exists in the system?

Answer (score 1):

It could be written as follows:

`$(eval PkgName := $(shell pacman -Qq zsh | awk '{print $$1}'))`

`$(if ${PkgName},,pacman -Sy --noconfirm zsh)`

That should do it all without errors.

Thanks again, I hope this could help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up the `$(if cond,true_path,false_path)` with the make's conditionals `ifeq`.

For your use case you can define a make variable `$(STATUS)` and check within the if statement the absence of install.

```
STATUS := $(if $(strip $(shell pacman -Qq zsh | awk '{print $$1}')),,$(strip $(shell pacman -Sy --noconfirm zsh)))
```

Comment: Thanks, you point me into the right direction.  Yet, I found a simpler solution.